# R - update elements in list (in loop)

Tags: r, list

I'm learning R and hitting my head on this.
I have the following **working** code

```
  allA <- 0
  allB <- 0
  allC <- 0

  for(i in realismMeans){
    for(j in i){
       allA <- allA + j$meanA
       allB <- allB + j$meanB
       allC <- allC + j$meanC
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to use only 1 list but for the life of me I'm lost on how to use the list. Here's my attempt (**not working**)

```
  allList <- list()

  for(i in realismMeans){
    for(j in i){
      allList[[1]] <- allList[[1]] + j$meanA
      allList[[2]] <- allList[[2]] + j$meanB
      allList[[3]] <- allList[[3]] + j$meanC
    }
  }
```

I know the length of allList is fixed to 3.

Comment: What is `realismMeans`

Comment: It appears the first loop is adding to a value that does not exist.  Try initializing the list with a given length:  `allList <- rep(list(0), 3)`

Comment: Why do you use 2 for-loop in this case?

Comment: realismMeans is a list of lists (length 3)